# JNI error after converting jar to exe using launch4j

Tags: java, exe, launch4j

After using launch4j to convert my jar file into exe it gives me a JNI error that tells me to check my installation and try again after that it gives me another warning that says a java exception occured.

I've tried different ways such as choosing different options but it still doesn't work.

here is the log:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: fluidDynamicsProject/FluidDynamicSerial has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that the version of the JVM that is used by launch4j to run the program is less recent than the version of the compiler that compiled class fluidDynamicsProject/FluidDynamicSerial. You can try to set the minimum version in the launchj4 configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<launch4jConfig>
  ...
  <jre>
    ...
    <minVersion>11.0</minVersion>
    ...
  </jre>
</launch4jConfig>
```

Note that it's possible that launch4j doesn't support the latest versions of Java.

Or else, you can lower the target version you use to compile your classes.

Comment: sorry but where is this launch4j configuration file located?

Comment: @UjwalJoshi wherever you put it. I guess you're using the GUI. In which case you can set the minimum version number in the JRE tab.